# WebClient.Download() exception: Access to the path

Tags: c#, .net, exception, network-programming, webclient

I have a very simply code of:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(privateHTML, @"\\192.168.0.12\imagedepot\AT" + carID + ".jpeg");
```

However, i get the error:

> Access to the path '\\192.168.0.12\imagedepot\AT296866482.jpeg' is denied.

I can browse this folder from my machine (same one this app runs on), right click and create new text file.  The target is a windows 2008 server.  Any ideas?  That folder share is set to everyone with full.

When I change \192.168.0.12\imagedepot to be a mapdrive of Z:\ i get.

> Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\AT294577469.jpeg'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after comment:

Then this is perhaps a permissions/rights issue... what sort of application is it ? WinForms ? Windows Service ? ASP.NET ?

EDIT 2:

Now that it is clarified by the OP (see comments) that it is a Windows Service the problem is clear:
Accsessing Network drives/UNC paths from a service is definitely a permissions/rights issue as Service is usually NOT allwed to access a network share and/or a mapped drive!

see [Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service/182846#182846)

Comment: see thats the thing, i was using this just fine for like a month, i just switched it over to new install of winsows 2008

Comment: its a console app, an permissions for that folder is everyone,full.  which makes no sense, because like i said I can create a file manually using either of those paths.

Comment: does the console app run with the same user as when you try it manually ?

Comment: umm i'm not sure, i dont specify a user, but again that folder permisisons is Everyone and full.  everyone doesnt need a user.

Comment: I am NOT talking about the persmissions of the folder/share... BUT I am talking about the persmission/rights/user your console app is running under...

Comment: oh yes, the console app does use the same user.

Comment: then there is something weird going on with your OS installation... can you write to the share from within the console app using some other method (not WebClient) ?

Comment: Yeah i can use File.appendalltext to create a text file and it goes straight to Z:\

Comment: then I am out of ideas... sorry

Comment: hmm interesting, i put that code in directly above the line and it cant find that path.  I was trying that outside in a test code.  So yeah, it's a windows service console app and it cant find path

Comment: thanks for the help, but i really have been used that same exact code for like a month, my guess is this new install of winsows 2008 something must have been configured differently.