# VB Windows service that maps a drive then uses it

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, network-drive

[Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service)

My question is relatively similar, and I realize there are others that are.. but I can't get it to work. I am creating the service thru visual studio 2010.

I attempted to map using  WNetAddConnection2- and it successfully maps and is instantly lost (check if drive is mapped right after mapping it).

So I tried something else..
I saw some information about using WSH.. I added the reference and tried using wsh... didn't work.

I tried WNetUseConnection and that failed as well.

Attempted running the service under a different profile- that didn't work

Once I actually get access to the network drive, i need to copy files from that share into a local directory.

Maybe I'm missing the boat here but If someone could give me a thorough explaination of what is actually going on and a direction to head I can probably figure it out

Comment: Do you have to use a mapped drive? Can you just access the resource via the UNC name?

Comment: Why do you need to map it as a drive, why not just copy the files directly from the share?

Comment: Well.. I did try to access it via UNC but it is telling me that I dont have access to it. server has credentials and when i attempt to start the copy it fails

Comment: If you don't have access to it via the UNC then you won't have access to it as a mapped drive.  Mapping the drive is not the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity_members%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class' Impersonate Method with the credentials of a user that has access to that drive and then try to grab the files.