# cfdirectory a network drive

Tags: iis, coldfusion

This works:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" name="qry" directory="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Atlas\" >
</cfdirectory>
<cfdump var="#qry#">
```

So I know that cfdirectory is working. But this doesn't work:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" name="qry" directory="\\Vostro420\myDir\">
</cfdirectory>
<cfdump var="#qry#">
```

It doesn't fail: it just returns an empty result. I can copy/paste the address into Windows Explorer and it navigates to Vostro420\myDir\, so I know it's not a typo.

I'm trying to access a file that's on our local network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to check here is the permissions. If you are trying to access a remote / mapped network drive, the ColdFusion service will need to be changed to run as a user in the domain of the networked drive, and with permissions that allow it to read / write to that mapped drive.

So, make sure that ColdFusion has the correct permissions to access the systems on the mapped drive and you should be all set. :)

The Adobe ColdFusion help archives has a nice article on how to run ColdFusion as a specific user:

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/running-coldfusion-specific-user.html

Comment: My apologies for the double answer - submitted a new one instead of editing this one :)

Comment: plus 1 - it's usually permissions. Your syntax looks ok to me.

Comment: Much better is this approach in my opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7867064/376086

Answer (score -1):

I have this working on a server at home, but I attached the network location as a logical location. So instead of my path being:

//COMPUTERNAME/DIRECTORY

I'm using:

X:/DIRECTORY

The only times I have issues is when the network computer sleeps :P

Comment: ShortRound, that didn't seem to work for me.  I'm just getting the same (no) results.