# Why does DriveInfo.GetDrives() not get network mapped drive in windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service developed in .NET C# using VS 2010, I'm calling the `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` but it is not getting the `Z:` drive (a mapped network drive),

I did some googling and found some results pointing to windows account privileges, so I have tried all account types of service installer such as LocalSystem, User, LocalService, NetworkService but none worked and I still can't get the drive `Z:`.

I did another test, debugging the windows service (as a console application) and I can get drive `Z:` that way.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: Drive mappings a per-user setting.  The service probably is running with a different user account.  Don't use mapped drive letters in a service.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run the windows service with an account that has the network drive mapped, for example, the same account that you used to run as a console application. As Hans advised you should not be using mapped drives in windows services because they are a concept associated to a real user.

However if you really want to continue to use mapped drives see this related question for pitfalls and workarounds related to this specific situation:

[How to map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service)

Answer (score 2):

Drive mappings are associated with LUID and you could have multiple Authentication ID under the same user (e.g. service, normal integrity level, high integrity level etc).

You can have a normal integrity level process running in the user's session to provide the mapped drive list created by the user. This is [how Windows Explorer copies mapped drives for elevated setup programs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/02/19/mapped-network-drives-with-uac-on-windows-vista.aspx).