# Network mapped drive not showing DriveInfo.GetDrives() in C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

A network drive is mapped on our application server and drive name is Z.
When I am trying to get drives information am not getting Mapped drive (Z). Tried with below code:

```
 DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
 Response.Write("Drives Present in Server: </br>");
 foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
 {
     Response.Write("---Drive Name: " + d.Name + " Drive Type: " + d.DriveType + "</br>");                
 }
```

How do i get this mapped drive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029855/why-does-driveinfo-getdrives-not-get-network-mapped-drive-in-windows-service

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5b3ee65-4d08-4ee5-bba5-60a2a5b50d07/why-driveinfogetdrives-not-getting-networkmapped-drive-in-windows-service-which-i-developed-in

Comment: There's no such thing as a network drive. Mapped drives aren't real drives, they're (roughly) user-specific shortcuts that  point to shared folders on a remote server. Why don't you use the actual shared folder path?

Comment: Windows does have a [distributed file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/dfs-overview), which doesn't work through mapped drives at all.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Not exactly. At least with the .NET point of view. `System.IO.DriveType` enum has an item `Network` for network drives.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a "network drive" or that such a concept exists, or that `Z:` is accessible from other accounts or web apps

Comment: The letter `Z:` maps to a UNC path , eg `\\thatserver\thatfolder` that can be used directly from any account that has permissions to access that path. There's no need to use a mapped drive

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work for mapped drives as well. Just ensure that connection to the network is proper (eg., if VPN should be connected to access the network drive).

I'm having similar code and it was crashing when iterating through the mapped Z drive when VPN connection was lost. Also, to avoid crashing in deployments, add `try-catch` blocks.

Comment: Yes, when tried, the OP's code displays the network drives. Try-catch blocks are necessary, too.

Comment: It works only because the drive is mapped in the user's account. Running that code in a web app will fail. Using the actual UNC path the drive maps to would still work.  This has nothing to do with VPNs either. VPNs don't establish mapped drives. You'd only need an active VPN  if you wanted to connect to a work network remotely and then map a drive on the work network.