# MongoDB Window Service Connection to "data/db" on a File Server not Local Disk

Tags: mongodb, windows-server-2012

I have install **MongDB 2.2.2** on a **Windows 8 Server** and I cannot get the service to start. I am trying to connect to a db that is located on file server in the same network, but it will not start and I get this error:

```
"ERROR: dbpath (e:/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath."
```

`e:/data/db` is the mapped directory, and I have even tried connecting using `\\SERVERNAME\SharedFolder\data\db` and I still have the same results.

Comment: Windows 8 Server? (Windows Server 2012?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB service (running as a particular user), must have the proper credentials to access the server and drive (and directory). It's very likely unless you've created a new user (and run the service as that user) that it does not have access to the path you've provided.

Further, you can't as easily used a mapped drive as drive mapping takes place as an interactive user (which a service is ***not***). While there are complex [work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service), the better choice is to not use a mapped path and instead use the full (non-mapped) path such as `\\servername\storage\db`.

Comment: I have tried using the non-mapped method (\\SERVERNAME\SharedFolder\data\db) but I still cannot get the MongoDB Service to start.  Would you suggest that create a service level account to run the service with? Currently, I am just using an admin account to start the service. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the account needs access to the share. Does the admin acct have full access?

Comment: I just checked and the admin account does have full access.  I also tried to install the service with a different user but it did not work.

Comment: You confirmed the user has full write access as well? (It's burned me more than once giving a user "share" access, but forgetting they still need access to read/write files within the share.

Comment: I finally got it. I just created a new share on the storage server, and then only allowed the Admin user full access to this shared space.  Then I installed with the non-mapped method and it work.  Thanks for your help with this WiredPrairie!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your trying to start the service but a batch file would look like this:

```
@echo off 
set data="C:\mongo\data"
set log="C:\mongo\log"
@mkdir %log% 
@mkdir %data% 
set log=%log%\mongo.log"
bin\mongod.exe --dbpath %data% --logpath %log% --install 
net start mongodb
```