# PHP permissions on a VirtualBox Windows-guest shared folders

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, virtualbox

I have a PHP website with a backend batch/CRON job that runs ever so often and processes photos. The web and database servers and RAID storage are Fedora 14 boxes and the photo software runs in a Windows 7 VirtualBox on the storage server.

The storage array is loaded as a shared folder and shows up as E:\ under Network Locations.

The PHP exec command runs every minute via PHP-CLI looks like this:

```
exec("C:\\service\\photo_edit.exe --input-file E:\\photos\\photo_example.jpg --effect crossprocess --output-file E:\\photos\\user\\finished_example.jpg")
```

Running the command directly in the command line works. The thing is, PHP can't seem to use E:\ at all, even though I can access it through the Command Prompt. I also have to keep Windows in a VirtualBox because I have more services that edit files and run in Linux.

I need PHP to be able to work with these files on the web storage inside Windows.

Comment: "PHP can't seem to use E:\ at all" - What error does it give? Can't find/no permission/something else?

Comment: permissions... make sure that your webserver's account has access to both the share itself AND the underlying filesystem the share is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a permissions issue. Network shares mapped to a drive letter are a per-user setting. The user Apache runs as does not have that share mapped as `E:`.

Alternatives include:

1. Use the UNC syntax: `\\vboxsvr\whatever`
2. Map the drive for current Apache user (LOCAL_SYSTEM?) — [Does not seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service)
3. Change the user the Apache service runs as

Comment: Wow, I didn't know I could simply switch it to the UNC syntax. Seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

Does PHP have permission to access `E:\`? Just remember that when you run the command, you're probably an Administrator. PHP, on the other hand, is likely running with lower privileges.