# Unable to connect to MS Access database located in a network using php

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

I am developing a web application that should be connected to Access database. I am working using php. If my database is local, I don't have any problem. Originally the database is located in a network. When I test my webpage connecting to the network database, I get this error

```
Warning: odbc_exec() [<a href='function.odbc-exec'>function.odbc-exec</a>]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]  'T:\Chris\Test1.mdb' not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides., SQL state S1009 in SQLExecDirect
```

I know that this question has been asked by many people but I am not yet able to solve my problem. Does anyone has any idea where the problem occurred?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have a setting with the string '....name of the directory' instead of the directly path.

Comment: True, the name of the directory is the location of the database in a network drive.

Comment: If you read the error message closely. Your connection settings do not contain a path. Instead it contains the string '....name of the directory'

Comment: I presume you are replacing the actual directory path in the error message with `...name of the directory`, right? Otherwise the point @datasage made is correct. If you say it's working fine locally, but not over the network, does your php server have correct access to the network location?

Comment: @SoupyC, you are right. I have edited the error and put the right directory. The right access to the server location?? That is what I am not sure about. Could you tell me how I can make sure that?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you were replacing it for this post. Yes as @SoupyC mentioned, if the path is valid. You will need to make sure permissions exist for php/iis to access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP permissions on a VirtualBox Windows-guest shared folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710973/php-permissions-on-a-virtualbox-windows-guest-shared-folders). Seriously. I'm pretty sure that the Apache user does not know what `T:` is.

Comment: You might also want to consider using a UNC path to the file rather than a mapped drive letter. If you use a mapped drive then make sure the mapping exists for the user executing the process (IIS?)

Comment: It depends if you are hosting the application with IIS or Apache, and also what user account it is running under, etc. At a very basic level, does the web host have access to the T:\ drive? If you can get remote access to the server, then try to access that path and see if you can see the file.

Comment: @SoupyC, I can see the file. Thank you all of you. I am trying to solve it according to your suggestion. I will update you.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario and @Martin Wilson. I used UNC path as you suggested and now my problem is solved. In the administrator tool I used the IP address of the pc where the database resides rather than the `T:` derive.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by users comments. The solution is don't use network derive name like `T:`. Use the network path, like `\\IP address\db_folder\db_name.mdb`. This first needs sharing the folder on the network.

Comment: It isn't mandatory to use the IP address; the machine name is valid as well.