# Running a PowerShell script from C# to Pull Git Repository

Tags: c#, git, powershell, windows-services

First time asking a question here, as I'm a bit stumped on this one. I have a Powershell script to pull a git repository:

`git.exe --git-dir=C:\ReleaseStaging\QABuild\.git pull --progress "origin"`

The script works fine if I execute this in powershell.

The next step was to get a c# windows service to execute this powershell script. The output of the command is "'W:/QABuild' does not appear to be a git repository. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

The "W" drive is a mapped drive to my git repository and C:\ReleaseStaging\QABuild is where I clone the repository locally.

My next test was to run the same c# code in a ConsoleApplication and it worked fine. So I figured that my Windows service needed to run under different credentials to see that W drive, but that didn't work running under my local account either as I got the same error.

Here is the code that I'm using in my windows service:

```
        using(RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke()) {
            invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
        }

        string cmdArg = String.Format(@"C:\ReleaseStaging\PullChanges.ps1");

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
        runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg);

        pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(
          PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);

        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        var error = pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd();
        runspace.Close();
```

Any thoughts as to how to get a git repository to pull from a powershell script executed in a windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `git pull` implicitly is using the mapped drive. Using a mapped network drive in a windows service is notoriously difficult.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service) for some tips on how to do it. The simplest method is probably to use a UNC path instead of a mapped drive.