# BULK INSERT error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert a file from remote server to MS SQL server.

```
CONN = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ReadEMAPI.My.MySettings.IntradayDataConn").ConnectionString)
cmd.Connection = CONN
CONN.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "BULK INSERT BidAsk FROM '" & "G:\Intraday Data\EMAPI\SET\Test.csv" & "' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',', ROWTERMINATOR='\n',KEEPNULLS)"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
CONN.Close()
```

I got this error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file ""G:\Intraday
>   Data\EMAPI\SET\Test.csv"" could not be opened. Operating
>   system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

However, when I ran the sql command exactly the same in MSSQL Management Studio on the server, it was able to execute correctly.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe the drive is not known as "G" when entering remotely?  Perhaps something like this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482825/find-unc-path-of-a-network-drive

Comment: If `G:` is a network path, it's generally better to use UNC paths. Also ensure SQL Server Service account has access to the directory.

Comment: When you logged in to SSMS to run the command were you using Domain or Windows credentials by chance? When that happens drive and share access for `BULK INSERT` happens in the context of your own Domain or Windows account. If the VB program uses different Domain or Windows credentials then the `BULK INSERT` happens in the context of that Domain or Windows account. If the VB program uses SQL Login credentials then the `BULK INSERT` happens in the context of the Domain or Windows account under which the SQL Server service is running.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning access to the file will be under the credentials of the SQL Server Service Account, not the Login/User who is connected to the instance. Otherwise, for example, it would be impossible to perform a `BULK INSERT` with a SQL Authentication Login. The `LOGIN` simply needs permission to perform Bulk Operations.

Comment: Your error message looks suspicious. Is this your actual code? It makes no sense to hard code a path and use concatenation with a bunch of literals to create a dynamic query that is completely static.