# Windows application update from a shared drive - Visual Studio Publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish, shared-drive

I would like my application to look for update from a shared drive. So if a new version is published to a shared drive, all users get an update message when they start the application.

I am using visual studio publish feature. It ask for Installation Folder URL. When I choose a folder, it gives error "The string must be a fully qualified URL or UNC path".

What will be the UNC path for following folder?

> D:\InstallationFolder\

I tried `\\\D\InstallationFolder\`,` and it gives me warning
**"Warning: Unable to view published application at \\D\InstallationFolder."**

Help

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

First：See [Publishing ClickOnce Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/31kztyey(v=vs.110)) on MSDN.

In the How will users install the application? page, select the location where users will go to install the application:

> If users will install the application directly from the file share, click From a UNC path or file share, and then click Next. (This is for publishing locations of the form c:\deploy\myapp or \server\myapp.)

`UNC path`

`UNC` stands for universal (or consistent, uniform) naming convention, and is a syntax used to access folders and files on a computer network. The syntax is as follows:

```
\\<computer name>\<shared directory>\
```

Followed by any number of directories, and end with a directory or file name.

Last:

[Find UNC path of a network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482825/find-unc-path-of-a-network-drive)

Refer to dlauzon's answer:

[image]

Or use `net use`:

Refer to Lachlan Dowding's answer here:

In Windows, if you have mapped network drives and you don't know the UNC path for them, you can start a command prompt (Start → Run → cmd.exe) and use the `net use` command to list your mapped drives and their UNC paths:

```
C:\>net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote  HTTPS             Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Q:        \\server1\foo             Microsoft Windows Network
OK           X:        \\server2\bar             Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

Note that this shows the list of mapped and connected network file shares for the user context the command is run under. If you run `cmd.exe` under your own user account, the results shown are the network file shares for yourself. If you run `cmd.exe` under another user account, such as the local Administrator, you will instead see the network file shares for that user.

Comment: Does it help you?