# file_put_contents(Z:/test/39361_1657094148_elicense.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in network shared drive/folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am developing a web application using laravel, and the application requires me to create a pdf file and save it to be downloaded later.I have successfully created the file from view using laravel-snappy and i can download it on the browser.**The problem is that; when i try to save the file in a network shared drive using the *file_put_contents* function, I get the error captioned on the question's title.**

When I change the path from network drive, to let say disk *D:/test* of the server, the file is successfully saved in that location.

I have tried the following ways to achieve it as below

`$saving = "Z:/test";`
Z is the network drive (drive of th shared folder)

1.By using barry laravel snappy facade

`$pdf = PDF::loadView('file',compact('data'));`

When I return it as below it works
`return $pdf->download($fileName);//download the file`

But when saving it in the path it gives me the error I mentioned above
`$pdf->save($savePath);//saving the file`

2. Using the file_put_contents function

`$output =  $pdf->output();`

`file_put_contents($savePath,$output);`

Still getting the same error

3.Using the copy function
In the same drive/disk but different folders it works
`$path1 = "D:/files";`
`$path2 = "D:/test";`
`copy($path1,$path2);`

But when i change $path2 to the shared network drive/folder

`$path1 = "D:/files";`
`$path2 = "Z:/test";`
`copy($path1,$path2);`

It does not work and I get a different error as shown below
`copy(Z:/test/39361_1657094148_elicense.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

When i change from `Z:/test` to IP of the shared folder as  `\\x.x.x.x\test` it gives me another error as `copy(\\x.x.x.x\test/39361_1657094148_elicense.pdf): failed to open stream: Invalid argument`

I have tried this for 3 days now but nothing is working When I save to that shared folder/drive

I really need help. Anyone with an insight on how I can get out of this problem I will appreciate

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does the user under which the website account runs have that network drive mapped? If not, try using the equivalent UNC path instead of the drive-letter version. And make sure that account has permissions to it as well

Comment: Yes, the network drive is mapped

Comment: And @ADyson, sorry what's the UNC path and how do i use it

Comment: Regarding permission, the folder has  full control set

Comment: UNC path is like `\\server\share\folder\file.txt ` format. Every network drive is accessible by such a path (mapping it as a drive is just a convenience). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482825/find-unc-path-of-a-network-drive for ways to find out the UNC path of your drive.

Comment: `the folder has full control set `...full control for who, though? As I explained above, your web application will run under a different account than the one you log into the computer with. Assuming you're using IIS, you can check the IIS application pool settings for the PHP site, to find out and/or modify what account it uses. (But don't set it to run as yourself, instead use a service account which doesn't belong to a specific human being, or one of the built-in accounts). If you're using Apache or something else as the server, consult the relevant documentation for how to achieve that.

Comment: Using the UNC path, it is giving me another error as ```file_put_contents(\\x.x.x.x\Data/39361_1657271757_elicense.pdf): failed to open stream: Invalid argument``` with x.x.x.x being the ip address and Data is the shared folder

Comment: Seems like you forgot to put the path in quote marks...it's still a string! Also you need to use backslashes throughout, not forward slashes.

Comment: I am putting it like file_put_contents("\\\\x.x.x.xx\\Data\\39361_1657275298_elicense.pdf", $output); but getting it like ```file_put_contents(\\x.x.x.x\Data\39361_1657275298_elicense.pdf): failed to open stream: Invalid argument``` without quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was with the permission, my application had no right to write to that network shared folder
The solution was to open the directory and then save the file

I find the solution from this link *https://www.codedwell.com/post/21/reading-file-list-from-a-mapped-windows-network-drive*

Thanks for the insight @ADyson