How to expand path to UNC including all server domain information?
I need to compare path strings, and understand if the describe the same folders.  I can't work with any difference in the given information of an UNC path.
How to convert a path into the full UNC version, including server domain information, in Delphi?
thispath  : String;

thispath := 'x:\testfolder_on_server';

thispath :=  ExpandUNCFIlename( thispath ) ;   //   '\\myserver\testfolder_on_server\'

But what I need is the UNC Path including all the domain information  for my server path.
'\\myserver.local.company_name\testfolder_on_server\'

idea for a solution :
function ExpandUNCFilename2(const PathStr: string; IncludeFullserverInfo : Boolean ): string;
begin
     if IncludeFillserverInfo  then
       begin
       ///
       ///    ExpandUNCFilename  returns  e.g. \\myserver.domain.company.com\testfolder#1\testfolder#2
       ///
       Result :=  ExpandUNCFilename( PathStr);
       end
       else
       begin
       ///    should return  e.g. \\myserver\testfolder#1\testfolder#2
       ///

       Result := .... ???
       end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var  path  :  String ;
begin

     path :=  'E:\temp\name__10.ini';

     edt_UNC1.text := ExpandUNCFilename2( path, True ) ;

end;

My own solution would go like this , split path  into string list ,   if first item is with server prefix '\\'   delete all char after first occurrence of a '.'; any better solution ?  For some of my attached network drives the Delphi function ExpandUNCFilename  like net use returns the complete server name sometimes not ....

Delphin - really?! Also hosts don't need to have a domain at all, that's why you cannot force finding one for a hostname.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482825/find-unc-path-of-a-network-drive

net use  ,path copy tool: not sure why and when they report \myserver.local.company_name\ testfolder vs. \myserver\testfolder , but this is why my string comparison fails
