# How do you permanently delete a persistent mapped drive on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: persistent, mapped-drive, sysinternals

I found the answer to how to create a persistent mapped drive here:
[Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service#)

I used the sysinternals tools to set it up and it works perfectly.  The server was cloned and now it shows up there as well.  Using the sysinternals tools, I am able to delete it, but it shows back up on reboot.  Nothing I try seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In all my searching, I finally found the solution.
This works for Windows Server 2012.

Go to search and look for Group Policy Editor and click on what comes up.

In the Group Policy Editor 
- Computer Configuration 
-- Windows Settings 
--- Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)

Under Startup there should be a script called MapX (X=the drive letter you are trying to delete).
Remove this script and reboot and the mapped drive should be gone.