# Dir$ is returning 'path not found' error on networked drives

Tags: lotus-notes

An agent I wrote in 2003 has been happily running all these years.  Just recently I got a report that it's throwing an error.  The agent does a Dir$ on a mapped network drive where there are a collection of files.  It generates a list of the file in the directory and presents it to the user via a dynamically built web page.  After doing some testing, I found the problem is the Dir$ call.  It works ok if the Dir$ is done on one of the local drives like C: and D:.  But the Dir$ on a network drive generates a 'path not found' error.

- I checked things like making sure the drive is pointing to a legit folder with files in it.
- I checked the privs on the account which the agent is running under.
- I checked the security to the mapped drive.

I'm running Domino 901 FP4 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Any other ideas on what I can check?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service). The first answer explains what the issue is, but the solution given would require you to write a new service that starts the Domino server service. I think the third answer looks like a simpler solution that you could configure easily.

Comment: Thanks Rich.  I ended up running Domino as an app for now.