# PIP installed pywin32 service fails: Incorrect function

Tags: python-3.x, windows-services, pywin32

Running Python 3.6.5, PyWin32 223.
After install I have included the the C:\Python32\lib\win32 folder in path.

I am just running the normal testService shell that seems to be all over the internet.  Can be found below.

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

I can "compile" and install the service fine, as soon as I run it I get an error to check the system logs.  When I do I get the following error.

> The Test Service Process service terminated with the service-specific error Incorrect function..

I have not been able to find any help through google from this decade.  I am new to the library and the only help I found was to add its lib to the path.  If its a path error, its no longer that.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't get your error. Here's an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115336/Using-Python-to-Make-a-Windows-Service.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was a permission issue.  I request root for 30 seconds and worked like a charm.  Just FYI if anyone is having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the way I run the python module. Instead of executing the Python script, I use

```sh
$ python -m module
```

This works correctly when running in the appropriate directory but when running as a service, the module could not be found. So the solution if executing modules directly with Python is to *pip install* the module so that it can be found by the service.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was due to the fact that the python script I was trying to run as a service wasn't in the same drive of the python installation. Also check this [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42779364/11764049).