# Java application running as a service does't not show mapped drives using File.listRoots()

Tags: java, swing

I have a java application running as a service. When I call File.listRoots() to display all drives including mapped drives (like X, Z), it only shows local drives (like C, D etc.) If I run my application in Application mode i.e. in current logged-in user context, I am able to see all the drives (including mapped one). Is there a way to list out n/w drives while running the application as a service? If possible, can anyone share a sample code to do so?

Thanks..

Comment: Sounds like a Windows question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service