# PHP mkdir doesn't work if the path is on mapped network drive

Tags: php, windows, cifs, network-share

I am trying to make a folder with `mkdir`, it will work as expected on a local drive, but it will fail with `No such file or directory` if I use a mapped network drive. I ran into this a year or so ago, and solved it with some `net use` trickery, but can't remember what it was.

An example command: `mkdir("Z:\\Mydir\\Subdir\\", 0777, true)`, this fails. But `mkdir("C:\\Mydir\\Subdir\\", 0777, true)` is successful.The permissions on the network drive are wide open for testing, and any user can create directories.

If I create a symlink for `C:\Mydir\` to `Z:\Mydir\` and use `mkdir("C:\\Mydir\\Subdir\\", 0777, true)` it instead throws an `Invalid arguments exception`.

Why does phps mkdir not seem to function correctly on mapped network drives?

Comment: Why do you believe that the local web server has permissions to create a directory on the network drive?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because the permissions are set to allow Everyone to have full control. Any user can do what they please with the share. Side question, does mounting the drive not permit, say the user the web server is using, to access that mount as the user it was authed with (`nfs use` with password and user)?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams your prompt was enough for me to find the answer. Which was to map the drive under SYSTEM. Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service