# Gradle copy file task fails to copy to mapped network drive via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, copy, network-drive

I am using Jenkins and running Gradle tasks to build a jar, executable and a setup.exe file. One of my gradle tasks is to copy the built setup.exe file to  mapped network drive on the agent in runs on. 
I am trying to copy the setup file to a folder on the mapped drive called 2.x. 
I get the error: 
"Cannot convert URL 'z:/Developers/Projects/builds/v2.x/' to a file."

```
task copySetup(type: Copy) {
from file("${projectDir}/Setup.exe")
into file ("z:/Developers/Projects/builds/v2.x")
}
```

If I run the task myself in the workspace then it works. Only fails when Jenkins runs it. I use a Gradle wrapper so it shouldn't be a Gradle version issue I think.

Comment: who is Jenkins running as? Is the Z drive mounted for that user?

Comment: @RavindranathBarathy It's running as the admin which has the network drive mapped. I have run the task via cmd in the Jenkins workspace and it works. It only fails when Jenkins tries to run the task itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got my answer from this post by ForcePush: [Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service)

Even though Jenkins runs as the user account I used to map the network drive, the service does not see any mapped network drives. The answer by ForcePush solves this problem.