# using mapped drive in airflow SSHOperator

Tags: ssh, airflow

I have a script stored on a drive mapped to `W:` on a remote windows server.

I set up this task in airflow:

```py
t2 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_con_id = 'svr07',
    task_id = 'test_R', 
    command = 'C:/[path to R]/Rscript.exe W:/[path to script]/script.R', 
    dag = dag)
```

However it doesn't seem like I can use mapped drives in an SSH connection.

Is there any way to pass a multiline `command`? One line to map the drive and the next to call the above to `cmd`?

Comment: separate commands with `&`

Comment: solution to the overarching issue is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service/4763324#4763324

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi-line command as following:

```
t2 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_con_id = 'svr07',
    task_id = 'test_R', 
    command = """
    # Code to Map your drive
    C:/[path to R]/Rscript.exe W:/[path to script]/script.R
    """, 
    dag = dag)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If I try `""" /n echo 1 /n echo 2 /n """` (with actual new lines instead of \n), and then look at the log it's printing either of those (when it had been when it was just one line)