# Accessing to NFS drive from windows service in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, nfs

I write a windows service with .net core 3.1. this service should access to NFS drive but throw the following Exception.

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path 'Z:...\sample.txt'.

I have installed this service with the same user that I logged on to the system (windows server). Also, I wrote a Console application for the test, the console application can access to the NFS drive.

Why I can access by the console and the same user but in windows service, I can not access the NFS drive.

Comment: Because your service doesn't have an interactive logon where network drives (like Z:\) are mapped. Have your service access the actual unc path instead.

Comment: Are you running as an Admin in VS.  VS doesn't automatically give Admin rights.  Code will run outside VS.  You can create a shortcut to VS.  Then start VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense as you can see here: [Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service/7867064#7867064) and
https://superuser.com/questions/650025/how-to-access-mapped-directory-from-a-windows-service

Why?

> persistent drive mappings are only restored on an interactive logon, which services typically don't perform.

My suggestion, go with the symbolic link. Seems the simpler of solutions

```
mklink /D C:\myLink \\127.0.0.1\c$
```