# How do connect to a network drive? (System.IO.IOException: the network name cannot be found)

Tags: c#

I have a network drive (N:) on the "berta" server. There is no way to get information about the directory or get the files (for example, \berta\N:\Somefolder) using System.IO.IOException: the network name cannot be found: '\berta\N:\Somefolder'

I'm trying this:

`var path = @"\\berta\N:\Somefolder"; var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);`

and get files:

`var filesAccept = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, $"*.zip.{extension}").ToList();`

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `var path = @"N:\Somefolder";` ? If it's not a network drive, but just a shared folder, then it would be `var path = @"\\berta\Sharefolder\";`

Comment: @B.O.B. yes, it works. But I need to get the files exactly the same way as in the question. Because I'm running windows service, but it can't get the path. Maybe I need to run windows service with rights to a network folder, but I do not know how

Comment: Where does this N drive actually exist? Is there a drive on the server named N, or is there a folder on the server mapped to an N drive on your machine? If the former then I believe that you should have a `$` after the drive letter rather than a `:`.

Comment: In that case you need to modify your question. Windows Services run under the Service account. Typically the System account does not have access to mapped network drives. Mapped network drives tend to belong to the Windows account that mapped them. This post has a way to map the drive for the system account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is an incomplete disk name.

complete in cmd: `net use`

my full disk title is `\\berta\nuoqe`